# Understanding Test-AzureRmPrivateIPAddressAvailability . Application gateway Private IPs are listed as available

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-application-gateway

I'm working on a script to figure out which IPs are available for an Application Gateway if there are already Gateways in the subnet.

When I use Test-AzureRmPrivateIPAddressAvailability and test an IP address that's being used by the frontend of an Application Gateway, it still outputs Available. Should it be unavailable?

Comment: Any more question? Or if the answer is helpful you can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure, but it seems that is a bug. The private IPs can associate to VM, Load Balancer and Application Gateway. And there should no difference that the availability shows. You can get more details about the [Private IP Addresses](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-ip-addresses-overview-arm#private-ip-addresses).

I did the test that when a private IP address associated with the VM and Load Balancer, then the availability of the IP shows False. Except for the Application Gateway.

**But don't worry**, it does not affect the function of the Application Gateway and the virtual network. When a private IP associated with the Application Gateway and then Azure will disallow other Application Gateways use it( when the Application Gateway create in a subnet and then the subnet can only contains Application Gateway, see [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-faq#is-application-gateway-always-deployed-in-a-virtual-network) ). Maybe this issue would be fixed in the future.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I was trying to get the IP addresses used by Application Gateways to avoid assigning that. I have a need to get an IP dynamically BUT have it be static, so I was working on a method to accomplish that.

Comment: @KathrineStack There is no command to get all the available IPs in the subnet. Maybe you should make a loop in the subnet to achieve that when the Test command is OK.

Comment: That's what I did. Didn't mean to say method, sorry. But I can't do it with App Gateways because yeah.. it doesn't.. report correctly.

Comment: Unluck, but it is being fixed. You could do that soon.